# How to perform broadcasting on 2 different 2-D arrays (Python / numpy)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If if have 2 numpy arrays, both 2-D with different shape:
x.shape = (2,2)
y.shape = (3,2)

How can I perform broadcasting using numpy in order to perform operations such as:
x * y, x - y

Thank you.

Comment: is it ok to fill the smaller array with zeros first?

Comment: Any operation is fine as long as: no for loop is used, and only numpy is imported. Thanks

Comment: What's the result shape supposed to be?

Comment: I am trying to perform eucledian distance on those 2 matrix. so from (2,2) and (2,3), with euclidan. the shape should come out to be (2, 3)

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to work with arrays with different shapes and sizes, you need to provide some kind of default value for when resizing the smaller array, in this case I´m going to fill it with zeros. The idea is to transform the smaller array to the same shape as the bigger one so `numpy` can do calculations, for example:

```py
import numpy as np

# sample data
rows = 2
cols = 2
a = np.array(np.arange(rows * cols).reshape((rows, cols)))
rows += 1
b = np.array(np.arange(rows * cols).reshape((rows, cols)))

print(a)
>>>
[[0 1]
 [2 3]]

print(b)
>>> 
[[0 1]
 [2 3]
 [4 5]]
```

Now you can resize the smaller one:

```py
if a.size < b.size:
    a.resize(b.shape)  # in-place resizing adding zeros 
else:
    b.resize(a.shape)

print(a)  # with extra zeros
>>>  
[[0 1]
 [2 3]
 [0 0]]
```

And then perform the calculations:

```py
c = a * b

print(c)
>>> 
[[0 1]
 [4 9]
 [0 0]]

d = a - b

print(d)
>>>
[[ 0  0]
 [ 0  0]
 [-4 -5]]
```